# Postgres update value with plus sign

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone please explain why this is failing?

```
testDB=# Update users set email = ‘Alex+check@test.com’ where id = 106;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "check"
LINE 1: Update users set email = ‘Alex+check@test.com’ where id = 1...
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a long shot but check your apostrophes. They look wrong.

Does this work if you cut/paste it?

```
Update users set email = 'Alex+check@test.com' where id = 106;
```

Your apostrophes: `‘foo‘`

My apostrophes: `'foo'`

It's subtle but I think you have some kind of unicode character instead of a simple `'`.